# ¿Como quitar clase a todos las etiquetas li siempre y cuando tengan id diferente a una seleccionada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Este es el codigo que uso para agregarle las clases y luego quitarles,
esta funcionando  pero si tengo mas menus  el codigo se ara gigante y no quiero que eso pase

```js
base_url = $('#base_url').val();

$("li#6").on('click', function() {

  url = $("li#6 a").attr('data');
  $("li#4").addClass('active');
  $("li#6").addClass('active');
  $("li#6 a").addClass('toggled');
  $("#paginas").load(base_url + url);
  
  // remover clases
  
  $("li#7").removeClass('active');
  $("li#7 a").removeClass('toggled');
  $("li#8").removeClass('active');
  $("li#8 a").removeClass('toggled');
})
// Siguiente  menu
$("li#7").on('click', function() {

    url = $("li#7 a").attr('data');
    $("li#4").addClass('active');
    $("li#7").addClass('active');
    $("li#7 a").addClass('toggled');
    $("#paginas").load(base_url + url);
    
    // remover clases
    $("li#6").removeClass('active');
    $("li#6 a").removeClass('toggled');
    $("li#8").removeClass('active');
    $("li#8 a").removeClass('toggled');
})
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando doy click en una etiqueta  li con una id
le quite las clases a todos los li con una id diferente

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar siblings, asi:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="id1">1</li>
  <li id="id2">2</li>
  <li id="id3">3</li>
  <li id="id4">4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer una selección con `:not`:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
 $(`li:not(#${this.id})`).css('color','red');
 $(this).css('color','black');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="a">Hola</li>
<li id="b">Hola</li>
<li id="c">Hola</li>
<li id="d">Hola</li>
</ul>
```